# Magento Print Invoice fatal error

Tags: magento-1.8, php-5.4, create-invoice

When we try to print an invoice from the Magento admin panel, we get this error message:

> Fatal error: Declaration of
>   Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File::__construct() must be compatible
>   with Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource::__construct() in
>   /var/www/html/includes/src/Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File.php on
>   line 41

We tried to apply the changes suggested in another [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516620/magento-php-5-4-pdf-invoice-zend-error), but we got a blank pdf invoice file.

We are using Magento 1.8 on PHP 5.4.40.

Kindly advise us on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please post more details about your environment? What version of Magento are you using? What version of PHP are you using? Thanks!

Comment: PHP : 5.4.40    Magento 1.8

Comment: Have you applied the PHP 5.4 patch?

Comment: I solved this by downloading a later version of the Zend framework, and dropping the Zend_Pdf into the `lib/Zend/Pdf/` directory.  I believe as @Joseph points out this is part of the php 5.4 update

Comment: hi, Its work a weeks ago. But last two days get the above error. Kindly advise this issue.

Comment: Hi, Now its working fine. Just disable the compilation and recompile.

Comment: Hi @Rat If you solved the issue means you can post an answer for it. It would help others who are all facing the same issue